# How long does Domination/Mind Control effect last?

Tags: xcom-2

I'm currently on my final mission (Commander/Ironman) and I've just triggered the pod (2 codexes, 2 gatekeepers) before the last hall. I've dominated one of the gatekeepers with my Commander Avatar and have a chance to dominate either a codex or another gatekeeper.

However, I'm not sure about the mechanics. Many threads say the domination lasts forever which is untrue. I can tell that from my personal experience playing Veteran/Ironman 3 weeks ago (pretty painful when mind control of a gatekeeper was lost on the final mission). My questions are:

1. Are there any differences in the effect comparing Psi Op and Commander Avatar (other that the former can be used once per mission)?
2. What would you dominate with a Pri Op in my situation? A codex or the second gatekeeper? Or, keep the charge for later turns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dominate and Mind Control are different abilites.

The Psion's Dominate ability lasts forever (or at least until the mission ends). You can only use it successfully once per mission though, after which it is unusable even if the target dies.

The Avatar's Mind Control is **only temporary** and lasts 4 turns. If the target is still alive when it ends, it can and will attack you. However, it can be used multiple times per mission and typically has a 100% hit chance.

Comment: One caveat: Dominate only lasts as long as the Psi Op is alive and still in the mission. If the Psi Op is killed or evac's out (obviously not applicable to the final mission), you will immediately lose control of the dominated enemy.

Comment: Is it 100% true that Avatar's Mind Control lasts 4 turns and not less?

Comment: @UserControl I got this from the wiki. I don't know if this applies to the Commander's Avatar and don't know their definition of 4 turns. If someone has more concrete details, please edit them into my post.

Comment: @UserControl I played this last night --- it lasts exactly 4 turns (the same length as its cooldown, so if you can survive 1 turn of your friend attacking you, you can mind control it again.)